# TensorFlow: Where is trained model stored and how to access?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, caffe

Where and how does TensorFlow store its models (graphs)? Is it within the `checkpoint` files?

I know that in Caffe, the model is stored in a `.caffemodel` file, which is used for deploying (testing) the model after it has trained.

I just trained the model in this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers), and now have the following files in my `/tmp/mnist_convnet_model` directory:

[image: files]

What file(s) contain the actual model?

For instance, if I want to classify a single image using this trained model, what file is used for the classification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the model is within the various `checkpoint` files -- although the `*.ckpt` file is now split into `data` and `index` files.  I'm not sure what's in the index file, but
the `*.data*` files contain the weight and bias values.
The `*.meta` files contain the graph: variables, data structures, transformations, etc.

[Here](http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/) is a nice tutorial on the care and feeding.

Comment: Ok, if the graph is contained within the *.ckpt files, what is the purpose of the *.pb file that is used as the GraphDef in the Image Recognition [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/image_recognition)? In the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py) here, it appears that the create_graph() method uses the .pb file to recreate the saved graph.

Comment: The `pb` and `pbtxt` files contain the graph (operations and connectivity), the parts that don't change during training.  `ckpt` contains the model parameters (values that training is supposed to change).

Comment: I see that in the tutorial that you linked in your answer, to import a pre-trained graph, they import the `meta` graph, and restore from the latest checkpoint. However, in the tutorial that I linked in my previous comment, only the `pb` "GraphDef" file is used for deploying the inception pre-trained model. the meta graph restoration method does not seem to be used in this case.

Comment: Also, what is the difference between the `.pb` and `.pbtxt` files? I cannot seem to find much info on these, but it seems that some of the tutorials on tensorflow's website create `.pb` files, while others do not.

Comment: `pbtxt` is simply the ASCII-serialized file.  It looks a lot like extracted source code for the graph.